# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c++'

Tags: docker, flask, deployment, dockerfile

This is the error that i am facing when building the docker image for my flask application and python:3-alpine3.11 but when i am trying to build it is throwing me this error all the other dependencies are getting installed

```
3.097 Collecting grpcio==1.44.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
3.131   Downloading grpcio-1.44.0.tar.gz (21.4 MB)
4.190      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 21.4/21.4 MB 24.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
5.626   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
5.962   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
5.969   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
5.969
5.969   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
5.969   │ exit code: 1
5.969   ╰─> [12 lines of output]
5.969       Traceback (most recent call last):
5.969         File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
5.969         File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
5.969         File "/tmp/pip-install-ob437sp_/grpcio_6a2c2c3634574af9a9ee89dd68375ce9/setup.py", line 256, in <module>
5.969           if check_linker_need_libatomic():
5.969         File "/tmp/pip-install-ob437sp_/grpcio_6a2c2c3634574af9a9ee89dd68375ce9/setup.py", line 203, in check_linker_need_libatomic
5.969           cpp_test = subprocess.Popen([cxx, '-x', 'c++', '-std=c++11', '-'],
5.969         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
5.969           self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
5.969         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
5.969           raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
5.969       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c++'
5.969       [end of output]
5.969
5.969   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
5.972 error: metadata-generation-failed
5.972
5.972 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
5.972 ╰─> See above for output.
5.972
5.972 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
5.972 hint: See above for details.
------
Dockerfile:5
--------------------
   3 |     COPY . /analysisx
   4 |     RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
   5 | >>> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
   6 |     EXPOSE 3000
   7 |     CMD python ./app.py
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by adding the `g++` package to your Docker image, this way:

```
# Use the Python 3.7 image as the base image
FROM python:3.7

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /analysisx

COPY . /analysisx

# Install necessary system packages, including g++
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 3000

CMD python ./app.py
```